Subset of $C^1([0 , 1])$ is open
Let $C^1([0 , 1],\mathbb{R})$ be the subspace of $C([0 , 1],\mathbb{R})$ of the functions that have a continuous derivative throughout $[0 , 1]$ with norm:
$\|f\|=\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \{ |f(x)|+|f'(x)| \}$.
Let $G=\{f\in C^1([0 , 1],\mathbb{R})  | f'(x)\neq 0,  \forall x\in [0 , 1]\}$
Show that $G$ is open in $C^1([0 , 1],\mathbb{R})$.
I tried to take a function $f$ and find an $\epsilon$ so that the ball with center $f$ and radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $G$ but I got stuck with the inequalities.
I also tried to write $G$ as a preimage of a continuous function given by the modulus of the minimum of the derivative but I got stuck on the continuity of such a function.
Some other hint.
Thank you very much for your help.

Suppose $f \in G$. Since $f'$ is continuous we see that $\epsilon=\inf \{|f'(x)|: 0 \le x \le 1\}>0$. If $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$ then
$g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ because $|f'(x)-g'(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$.

now i see , thanks so much
